# pandas:output differences between two columns of lists of strings

Tags: python, pandas, string, list, difference

I have a dataframe with two columns as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'pos_1':[['VERB', 'PRON', 'DET', 'NOUN', 'ADP'],['NOUN', 'PRON', 'DET', 'NOUN', 'ADV', 'ADV']],
               'pos:2':[['VERB', 'PRON', 'DET', 'NOUN', 'ADP'],['VERB', 'PRON', 'DET', 'NOUN', 'ADV', 'ADV']]})
```

and I am trying to output the differences between these two columns using apply.

```
df['diff'] = df.apply(lambda x: [i for i in x['pos_1'] if i not in x['pos_2']], axis=1)
```

my desired output for the diff column should be:

```
diff
1 []
2 ['NOUN','VERB']
```

but instead I get two empty lists in the diff column. I do not know which part I am doing wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If need compared both lists element wise and return differencies use `zip` with compare each pairs and last flatten it by nested list comprehension:

```
f = lambda x: [z for i, j in zip(x['pos_1'],x['pos_2']) if i != j for z in [i, j]]
df['diff'] = df.apply(f, axis=1)
print (df)

                               pos_1                              pos_2  \
0       [VERB, PRON, DET, NOUN, ADP]       [VERB, PRON, DET, NOUN, ADP]   
1  [NOUN, PRON, DET, NOUN, ADV, ADV]  [VERB, PRON, DET, NOUN, ADV, ADV]   

           diff  
0            []  
1  [NOUN, VERB]
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. is there a way to see both of the differences ['NOUN','VERB'], or better said output anything that is different